# DEM creation with C++ application

Tags: raster, dem, lidar, c++, gdaldem

I am implementing a **C++** application that must produce **DEMs** from **LIDAR** data. I am following the next workflow:

- Write .las files from lidar data.
- Use PCL algorithms to transform/filter the point cloud.
- Use GDAL/OGR to create the raster/grid.
- Create a 3D model (.obj) from raster.

In this process I am doing the next file conversions:

- From "*.las*" to "*.pcd*" (To work with PCL).
- From "*.pcd*" to "*vector format*" (i.e. "ESRI Shapefile") (To work with GDAL).
- From "*vector format*" to "*raster format*" (i.e. ".tif") (To generate the DEM).
- From "*raster format*" to "*.obj*" (To visualize the DEM in 3D).

I'm using *gdal_grid* to create the grid from *vector format* file and *gdal_dem* to create the DEM using GDAL interpolation algorithms.

I'm not sure If this is the best way to create a DEM from .las files. I want to use third-party libraries to transform, filter or interpolate the point cloud and PCL/GDAL have these tools.

Anyone with experience with DEMs can give me information / advice?

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable building software from source and are on a Unix flavor or OSX, you can go from .las to DEM using [PDAL](http://www.pdal.io/) and [points2grid](https://github.com/CRREL/points2grid). If you're on Windows, I have no idea if you'll be able to get points2grid to build, but you could try.

Both PDAL and points2grid have C++ APIs that you could integrate into your own C++ application. You can also use PDAL's command line executable to create DEMs.

The short instructions for a Unix/OSX system to get a points2grid-enabled PDAL command-line executable are:

- Make sure you have [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/); use your favorite package manager to install
- Download points2grid from Github: `git clone https://github.com/CRREL/points2grid.git`
- Build and install points2grid:

  `cd points2grid && cmake . && make && make install && cd ..`

  If you don't have write access to `/usr/local`, change that last bit to `sudo make install`
- Download PDAL from Github: `git clone https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL.git`
- Build and install PDAL with points2grid support:

  `cd PDAL && cmake . -DBUILD_PLUGIN_P2G=ON && make && make install && cd ..`

  Same caveat to `make install` as above
- Write a pipeline xml file to describe your gridding process (run `points2grid --help` for more information about the points2grid options):

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Pipeline version="1.0">
   <Writer type="writers.p2g">
    <Option name="grid_dist_x">6.0</Option>
    <Option name="grid_dist_y">6.0</Option>
    <Option name="filename">outfile</Option>
    <Option name="output_type">mean</Option>
    <Option name="output_type">idw</Option>
    <Option name="output_format">grid</Option>
    <Reader type="readers.las">
     <Option name="filename">mylasfile.las</Option>
  </Reader>
  ```
- Use `pdal pipeline` to create your DEM:

  `pdal pipeline mypipeline.xml`

That should create some `outfile.xxx` raster files.